# zfs-share vs. /etc/exports NFS export on Linux

Tags: linux, nfs, zfs

I am setting up a share of a large ZFS storage via NFS on Linux. As far as I understood there are two possible ways to configure this: by means of `/etc/exports` or by using `zfs-share`. I have not been able to find any clear explanation about the difference between the two methods: are they just two different ways of doing the same thing or do they lead to substantial differences (e.g. available features, performance etc.)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ZFS on Linux uses the NFS subsystem under the hood; the benefit of doing it using ZFS commands is mainly that you can configure the share and the underlying storage from a single set of management tools.